# Замена выбранного по-умолчанию элемента select

Tags: javascript

Есть автоматически сгенерированный список с уже установленным атрибутом `selected`, такой код генерится по-умолчанию для посетителей:

```html
<select id="size">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

Необходимо переставить атрибут `selected` со второго пункта на любой другой (скажем, на третий) при загрузке страницы.
Библиотека jQuery для работы не доступна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Просто установка значения в `select`

Для того чтобы установить для `select` опцию используйте свойство `value`:

```js
document.querySelector("#size").value = "30";
```

```html
<select id="size">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

#### Модификация DOM

Если вам надо именно модифицировать DOM и установить `selected` нужной опции, то для этого можно воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```js
document.querySelector("#size > option[selected]").removeAttribute("selected");
document.querySelector("#size > option[value='30']").setAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

```html
<select id="size">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Благодарю, код срабатывает, в части модификации DOM, однако значение value не передается в форму =( почему-то был уверен, что модификация при загрузке этого параметра будет аналогичная "ручной" активации пользователем... попробовал немного модицифировать:  `document.querySelector("#size > option[value='30']").click();`. но не срабатывает...

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('size').querySelectorAll('option')[2].selected = true;
});
```

```html
<select id="size">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('size').value = '30'
}
```

```html
<select id="size">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option selected="selected" value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function setSelect(newSelectNum) {

    var select = document.getElementById('size');
    var options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');

    // сбрасываем старый
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
      var option = options[i]; 
      if (option.getAttribute('selected') === 'selected') {
          option.removeAttribute('selected');
      }
    }

    // устанавливаем новый
    options[newSelectNum].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
}
```

Comment: Слишком большой код для такой простой задачи. Цикл можно вообще бесполезен. Он меняет для выбранной опции `"selected"="selected"` на пустой атрибут `"selected"`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, да, согласен, но как пример )